# Python Selenium Script Crashes After Adding If Else

Tags: python, selenium

I just need a little help as i have already developed my small script but adding a new functionality is creating problems. The problem is with adding If else statement. The script crashes if it does not find any element so I want to bypass it by placing an ifelse condition, i.e. if the element is present it should click the button else it should move on to the next line.

Below is my code

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input.whsOnd.zHQkBf').send_keys(password)

    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_id("passwordNext").click()
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.get(comment_url)
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-default yt-uix-button-empty yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup comment-action-buttons-renderer-thumb yt-uix-sessionlink sprite-comment-actions sprite-like i-a-v-sprite-like']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-small yt-uix-button-link comment-renderer-reply comment-simplebox-trigger']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("comment-simplebox-text").send_keys(comment)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-primary yt-uix-button-empty comment-simplebox-submit yt-uix-sessionlink']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The code i want to add is :

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath ...... exists,
then
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   print("Zoom in 4x. Successful")
else
   print("Element does not exist, it failed.")
```

Whether I add only ( if) or if (if driver.find_element_by_xpath("") the script crashes within miliseconds and doesnt even open.

Comment: That isn't Python syntax, so it shouldn't be a surprise that it crashes.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, as i searched it on stackoverflow and found these similar syntax everywhere, can you please tell me what is the if else syntax for python

Comment: There are numerous Python introductions and tutorials out there, please start with one of those: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F. If you're just going to copy and paste snippets, pick ones in the right language!

Answer (score 1):

You need to try to catch an exception, and if you  catch it, do something in `except` block. Speaking about your scenario you probably need to catch `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException`. So the code may look like:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   print("Zoom in 4x. Successful")
except NoSuchElementException:
   print("Element does not exist, it failed.")
```